# How to continue typing after auto-completed pair of brackets/double-quotes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, resharper

If you're a programmer you know how important is it to stay on the keyboard and keep the typing flow and simple.

Latest versions of Visual Studio and also Resharper pack adds this functionality which pairs all the brackets and quotes while typing. THIS IS GOOD, DON'T TAKE ME WRONG.

**But there is one little problem**
You need to take your hand off the keyboard's center and play with arrow keys(NOT GOOD AT ALL) when you hit the finishing pair to jump over it.

**Scenario**
*(gonna show the blinker location with ^ symbol)*

1. I am in the process of typing ***string test = "value"***
2. I start typing till hit the ***string test = "^***
3. And auto-pair does the favor and adds the second pair of quotes as soon as I put the first and the code looks like this in this stage with blinker located in between pairs ***string test = "^"***
4. I type the string between quotes and reach the finishing pair ***string test = "value^"***

   5a. Now I need to take my hand off the center of the keyboard and press two **right arrow keys**
   or
   5b. type another double quote. In this case the environment is smart enough not to type the second and jump over it. BUT if I am gonna end up typing it what is the point of pairing it anyways?

I am wondering if there is any key-press or combination which jumps over the second completed pair.

Comment: Learn to love the following things. Hitting END, and Ctrl + Arrow keys. Ctrl + Left/Right arrow skips over entire groups of code. Try it out... you'll get used to it.

Comment: Personally I type the extra double quote and semi-colon as I'm used to it and find it faster to do. Also for things like for loops and if statements, I type for/if then hit TAB twice, then type in your condition, then press ENTER and your cursor is inside the braces.

On a side note, for staying on the keyboard, I'd recommend using VsVim http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329

Comment: @Simon, thanks for the comment. Honestly Arrow key or Ctrl+Arrow key is the same to me. They both involve getting out of keyboard comfort zone. The same wit End. It's not the matter of getting used to but making things better. I am touch typing for years and have no problem hitting any key on the keyboard. (Standard Keyboard. You know what I mean)

Comment: @Hack, I also use that trick and it's very comfortable. However I can't find any similar trick for this case. I'll have a look at VsVim as I've never heard of it and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Resharper <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will put your semi column there.

***Complete Statement*** is a feature that inserts necessary syntax elements (braces, semicolons etc.) and gets you in position to start the next statement.

To check if it isn't overwritten by another key-combination go to:

Visula Studio 2010 >> Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard...

and type *Completestatement* int he ***Show commands containing:*** textbox.

Comment: Great recommendation. This ticks all the boxes. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Once you get to this point... 
string test = "value^"

Hit the **tab key** and it will move past the auto generated character. It works the same for brackets, parenthesis etc..

Comment: I upvoted this because in my experience with USA keyboards, the tab is consistently on the left and easy to train because most visual studio users I have worked with are using tab key all the time anyway.  however the navigation keys are different across devices and keyboards.   also this solution is one single keystroke, with no changes to VS settings

Comment: This does not work for me in **Visual Studio 2015** or **Visual Studio 2017**. Could I be missing something? I hate moving my hands from the "Home" row.

Comment: @JessieWestlake Are you sure it doesn't work ? This is how I do it in VS Community 2017 15.1 (resharper not installed)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Resharper, you can try using Ctrl+u.

This shortcut would replace and lowercase whatever letter after the "blinker".

In this case, you would replace and lowercase the ending quotation mark, which will leave you with a quotation mark.

The blinker will be placed after the quotation mark and your hands won't leave the center of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Press the 'End' key to take you to the end of the line. That will save you one keystroke

Comment: The only reason I do not like this method – although it's the one I use – is because I have to move my hand just as far to hit **End* as I do for **D-Right**